# jQuery datepicker value always US locale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, sharepoint, datepicker

I have a custom SharePoint form and in the form I have two date pickers

`Start Date` and `End Date`

I also have a `span` to display difference in days on date picker changed

```
function DatePickerChanged() {
        var startDate = new Date($('input[title="Start Date Required Field"]').val());
        var endDate = new Date($('input[title="End Date Required Field"]').val());  
        if (endDate >= startDate) { 
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) + 1;    
            $("#totalDays").text(diffDays);
        }
        else {
            $("#totalDays").text('-');
        }       
    }
```

I had my SharePoint locale settings set to US so this code worked just fine.
(Date format was MM/dd/yyyy)

Now I changed the locale settings to UK (Date format is now dd/MM/yyy).

So when my code runs now, `$('input[title="Start Date Required Field"]').val()` and `$('input[title="End Date Required Field"]').val()` return wrong values.

For example if I choose 10/06/2016 (which is 10th of June) my jQuery reads it as 6th of October??? How do I read these values correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Mention your required format when initializing your date picker.
$('#datepickerID').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'})

Comment: It's a SharePoint form, so it's a `<SharePoint:FormField>` control, it gets rendered as `<input type="date">` on load